# Is it possible to redirect server-side with internationalization in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redirect, next.js, server-side-rendering

So I have a small Next.js app, which has pages only allowed for logged in users. Nothing special there.
To manage the authenticated routes I wrote an HOC (called withAuth) that redirects on the server, to avoid pages flashing on the client. It works great so far, but I have the issue, that my app is internationalized. So currently the user only gets redirected to the login in the default language (English), but I would prefer to keep their language selected.

Unfortunately, useRouter() is only available on the client, so my first approach did not succeed (I should have known better). This is my code:

### auth.tsx

```
import redirect from "../utils/redirect";
import * as React from "react";
import { sendData } from "../utils/sendRequest";

export const withAuth = <T extends object>(C: React.ComponentClass<T>) => {
  return class AuthComponent extends React.Component<T> {
    static async getInitialProps({...ctx}: NextPageContext) {
      await sendData('GET','/user').then(response => {
        if (!response || !response.success) {
          redirect(ctx, "/login");
          return {
            user: null,
          };
        }else return {
          user: response.user,
        };
      }).catch(err=>{console.error(err)})

    }

    render() {
      return <C {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
};
```

### redirect.ts

```
import Router, {useRouter} from "next/router";

const redirect = (context: any, target: string) => {
  let lang = "";
  /*if(!(useRouter.locale == "en")){
    lang = "/"+useRouter.locale; This wont work
  }*/
  if (context.res) {
    context.res.writeHead(303, { Location: /*lang+*/target });
    context.res.end();
  } else {
    Router.replace(/*lang+*/target);
  }
};
export default redirect;
```

### profile.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { withAuth } from "../components/auth";

//...

class ProfileClass extends React.PureComponent<{}> {
  render() {
    return <Profile />;
  }
}

export default withAuth(ProfileClass);
```

I am greatful for any ideas how to solve this problem :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution with `getInitialProps` in `_app` page.

You can access a `router` instance from the `getInitialProps` context object that can in turn access the current locale. Note that the `router` object is only available to the context passed to `_app`'s getInitialProps - but not available to the context passed to the other pages.

```js
// pages/_app.tsx

static async getInitialProps({ router, ctx }: NextPageContext) {
    const lang = router.locale;

    await sendData('GET','/user').then(response => {
        if (!response || !response.success) {
            redirect(ctx, `${lang}/login`);
            return {
                user: null,
            };
        } else {
            return {
                user: response.user,
            };
        }
    }).catch(err => { console.error(err) })
}
```

---

### Solution with `getServerSideProps` for other pages.

Since `locale` information can't be accessed from a page with `getInitialProps`, you can use `getServerSideProps` instead. Doing so involves refactoring the existing logic to fit into `getServerSideProps` implementation.

First, we'll repurpose `withAuth` and separate the logic for getting the user. This will add the `user` object to the `context` and pass it to `getServerSideProps`.

```js
// /components/auth

export function withAuth(gssp) {
    return async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
        try {
            const response = await sendData("GET", "/user");
            if (response && response.success) {
                // Add user to context to be used in `getServerSideProps`
                context = { ...context, user: response.user };
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }

        return await gssp(context); // Pass `context` and continue on to call `getServerSideProps`
    };
}
```

Then, `withAuth` can be used to wrap the `getServerSideProps` function in your page, where the redirect will happen if the `user` isn't set.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { withAuth } from "../components/auth";

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = withAuth(async (context: : GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
    if (!context.user) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: `/${context.locale}/login`,
                statusCode: 303
            }
        };
    }

    return {
        props: { 
            user: context.user 
        }
    };
});

class ProfileClass extends React.PureComponent<{}> {
    render() {
        return <Profile />;
    }
}

export default ProfileClass;
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer, but after a minute when I thought it worked, I got the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'locale' of undefined` When I checked in the documentation https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps, I noticed, that context does not contain the property router... :/

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same mistake. When I pass ```{ctx, router}:NextPageContext```  as parameters to getinitialProps, it throws the error, that NextPageContext is not the right type. When I remove the type declaration, it again logs the error mentioned above.

Comment: You're right, my current solution doesn't work. The `router` object is only available in `AppContext` - the context passed to the _app's `getInitialProps` - but not available to the context passed to the other pages.

Comment: @Bexy-Lyn I've updated my answer to include a possible solution using `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Yes, I have come to the same conclusion by now. GetServerSideprops does a better job.